# multiple monitors "The display settings could not be saved"

Tags: display, graphics-card

I have a 2048MB ATI AMD Radeon R9 270 (ATI) graphics card. Everything works fine with 2 monitors, but when i try to add a third monitor in screen resolution settings this error shows up: "The display settings could not be saved. Please try a diffrent combination of display settings."

The monitors are connected in this way: DVI,DVI,DP->DVI.

Is it the graphics card that does not support three monitors?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't dug up the specs sheet for that particular GPU, but if it's anything like the AMD GPU in my laptop, it is *only capable of generating 2 DVI signals*. Don't be fooled by the DP -> DVI adapter; unless that's a ~$20+ **active** adapter, it's just telling the GPU to pump a DVI signal over the DP connector, which means you're trying to drive 3 DVI signals (an active adapter will take a DP signal and convert it to DVI, the cheap plastic "passive" adapters you get with graphics cards and such just tell the GPU to output a different type of signal over the port).

Comment: What setup should I use to get 3 monitors working?

Comment: You should use an [active DisplayPort to DVI adapter](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?gclid=Cj0KEQjwyMafBRCU7OCRyc2vitsBEiQAKV4H9BUlI0UUAVHihetNR6SAfWxJs1lg0BpDAQWm9yqGhIsaAmQ98P8HAQ&Item=N82E16812200949&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleAdwords&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-_-pla-_-Audio+Video+Converters-_-N82E16812200949&ef_id=U9GHMQAABdHoHPXS:20140818170346:s) to hook up a DVI monitor to your DP port.